# Integrate JQuery with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Problem :

- How can I integrate my jQuery code with HTML?
- The code is working in Chrome console but I have to integrate it with HTML
- How should i call the below jQuery code in HTML?

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.ibody tr').each(function (a, b) {
        var count=0;
        var name = $('.cl', b).text();
        if(name.indexOf(".CSV")!==-1 && name.indexOf("TAS")!==-1){
            var d= a-9;
            var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
            iframe.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.src = `https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do?
ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param=${d}`;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: place it inside a <script></script> tag after importing Jquery.

Comment: import your jQuery: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`, then add your script inside script tags: `<script>/* JavaScript goes here */</script>`. If this "doesn't work", try to debug using the console (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome, or f12). If it doesn't work, then it's not related to *"How can I integrate my Jquery code with HTML."* and you should ask a different question.

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried but still it's not working. My JQuery code is wroking properly in chrome console but i want to integrate it with HTML and I am not able to do that. Can you please help ?

Comment: Hi Martin, I am getting below errors :
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at test.html:7

Answer (score 0):

## Your Script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
$('.ibody tr').each(function (a, b) {
var count=0;
var name = $('.cl', b).text();
if(name.indexOf(".CSV")!==-1 && name.indexOf("TAS")!==-1){
var d= a-9;
var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
iframe.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.src = "https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param="+d;
}
});
});
</script>
```

and if you wanted to call the function either on a button click you could do like this for example

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
// let us say this is your jquery function
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("p").hide();
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>This is a heading</h2>
    
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
    
    <button>Click me</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi Jelord, Thanks for such a quick response. I have tried it but it's not working :(

Comment: just include you're script on you're html

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is nothing but a javascript helper library. So to use any library, first you need to tell HTML that you are writing some functions from that library.
To do that , we need to include the library before you write any code that uses that library. In your case Jquery.

So 1st add the library using

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use any functions from that library.. in the same HTML file or in a different js file.

To use it in the same HTML file, write your code in the   tags.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
    $('.ibody tr').each(function (a, b) {
    var count=0;
    var name = $('.cl', b).text();
    if(name.indexOf(".CSV")!==-1 && name.indexOf("TAS")!==-1){
    var d= a-9;
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader' + count++;
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    iframe.src = "https://www.shipper-ml.com/viewReports.do?ctrl=reportListForDownload&action=DownloadReport&param="+d;
    }
    });
    }); 
</script>
```

To use it in a different file,

add your code in a new file (mycode.js), and use the relative path to it in the html file

```
<script src="mycode.js"/>
```

Comment: Hi Ashwin, Thanks for such a quick response. I have tried it but it's not working :(

Comment: @Shivangi  What is the error you're getting ?? and where have you added the <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> tag ?

Comment: Hi Ashwin, I am not getting any error, it's displaying a blank page. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
               
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: @Shivangi ,You have an empty body tag . What your code does is , it loops through all table rows. But since you dont have any table, the ".each" loop does not execute.

Comment: Can you help me with what sshould I add in body tag ?

Comment: Well that depends on what you're trying to do.. I don't think you'll get a solution for that here,

Comment: Can you give me your personnel mail id, so that I can mail you the entire code. Please help :(